# Why cant compile if i use CStringArray as method's argument

Tags: c++

This is C++ Win32 Program.
I have made a Method, But this is not compiled.

I expect that the cause of problem is using CStringArray as method's argument.

```
Ipc3dxContainerPtr KmCdmMakeMultiProjectAction::FindLastFolder
(Ipc3dxContainerListPtr folderList, CStringArray folderNameArr)
{
    Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = NULL;
    // skip other process
    return folder;
}
```

And This Called by this.

```
Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = FindLastFolder(folderList, s_ForlderName);
```

Can i get some advise?
Thank you.

Comment: And the compilation error is?

Comment: Richard Critten // Sorry! error is this " error C2248: 'CObject::CObject'"  : Cant't access private member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
Ipc3dxContainerPtr KmCdmMakeMultiProjectAction::FindLastFolder
(Ipc3dxContainerListPtr folderList, CStringArray folderNameArr)
```

`CStringArray folderNameArr` is passed by value. This will trigger the copy constructor of `CStringArray` which will attempt to copy it's base class, `CObject`, and `CObject` cannot be copied because its copy constructor is `private` specifically to prevent copying. In C++11 and newer, the copy constructor would be `delete`d, most likely giving you a much easier to understand error message.

Solution: Pass by reference: `CStringArray & folderNameArr` if you don't want `folderNameArr` to be altered inside the function, use `const CStringArray & folderNameArr`. If you want to alter a copy of the parameter, but not the original, make a new `CStringArray` and `CStringArray::Append` `folderNameArr` to it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you declare `folderList` as an `object` and attempt to use it here,

```
 Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = NULL;  <-- Error Here
```

and not as a `pointer to object`. If your `class` is not set up to handle that circumstance, the `compilation` `error` is likely coming from handling within the `class`.

The same would apply to why

```
Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = FindLastFolder(folderList, s_ForlderName);
```

is not working. So, basically just change `folderList` to be `*folderList`.

Comment: Nick Pavini. Thank you for your comment And Sorry not enough my explain about problem. The cause of error was CStringArray. And I solved this. My original source is wrote what insert object in "Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder" and the other processes. But just i didn't write my question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First Sorry that Explaining was not enough.
And solved this.

```
void KmCdmMakeMultiProjectAction::MethodA()
{
    CStringArray s_ForlderName;
    s_ForlderName.Add("Hi");

    Ipc3dxContainerListPtr folderList = cabinet->GetContainerList();

    Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = FindLastFolder(folderList, s_ForlderName);
}

Ipc3dxContainerPtr KmCdmMakeMultiProjectAction::FindLastFolder
(Ipc3dxContainerListPtr folderList, CStringArray folderNameArr)
{
    Ipc3dxContainerPtr folder = NULL;
    // skip other process
    folder = (Ipc3dxContainerPtr)folderList->GetItem(0)
    return folder;
}
```

That failed source. And I can solve with editing like this.

```
Ipc3dxContainerPtr KmCdmMakeMultiProjectAction::FindLastFolder
(Ipc3dxContainerListPtr folderList, CStringArray& folderNameArr)
{
     \\CStringArray folderNameArr -> CStringArray& folderNameArr
}
```

I still don't know why happen this problem.
Because i'm not understanding about c++'s basic theory.
Anyways I solved this problem.

Need to referenced by people have same problem, Thank you.